# OpenPyxl - difficulty getting cell value when cell is referencing other source

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I have a spreadsheet which references/caches values from an external spreadsheet.  When viewing the cell in Excel that I want to read using OpenPyxl, I see the the contents as a string: `Users` .

When I select the cell in Excel, I see the actual content in the Formula Bar is `='C:\spreadsheets\[_comments.xlsm]Rules-Source'!C5`. I do not have the source spreadsheet stored on my machine.  So, it appears Excel is caching the value from a separate spreadsheet as I am able to view the value `Users` when viewing the local spreadsheet in Excel.

When I read the cell from the local spreadsheet using OpenPyxl, I get `='[1]Rules-Source'!C5`.

It is my understanding that OpenPyxl will not evaluate formulas.  However, the string `Users` has to be cached somewhere in the XLSM document, right? Is there any way I can get OpenPyxl to read the cached source rather than returning the cell formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Excel does cache the values from the other sheet but openpyxl does not preserve this because there is no way of checking it.